# Не удаётся сделать первый коммит Unity 2021 Github Desctop

Tags: unity3d, github, git-commit

Возможно я плохо ищу, но мне так и не удалось найти хорошего ответа на этот вопрос.

Я создаю репозиторий через Github Desctop, затем создаю внутри него проект Unity версии 2021. Про стандартный .gitignore не забываю.

В итоге, получается список изменений в количестве около 16-ти тысяч, среди них, кажется, даже то, что было добавлено в гитигнор.

При попытке сделать коммит этого дела, программа "думает" не менее 15 минут, а затем выдаёт не менее внушительный список разнообразных ошибок.

Почему-то я уверен, что проблема состоит в порядке выполненных мной действий, но как делать правильно я не нашёл. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: *"Про стандартный .gitignor не забываю."* - Файл называется `.gitignore`

Comment: Вы правы, что заметили мою опечатку, может у вас есть по делу ответ?

Answer (score 1):

Моя ошибка найдена. У меня действительно не срабатывал .gitignore по причине того, что пути к игнорируемым файлам были закомменчены.

В стандартном файле .gitignore перед именем путей по умолчанию стоит слеш (/).

Вот мой вариант исправленного .gitignore:

```
# This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory
#
# Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore
#
[Ll]ibrary/
[Tt]emp/
[Oo]bj/
[Bb]uild/
[Bb]uilds/
[Ll]ogs/
[Uu]ser[Ss]ettings/

# MemoryCaptures can get excessive in size.
# They also could contain extremely sensitive data
/[Mm]emoryCaptures/

# Recordings can get excessive in size
/[Rr]ecordings/

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# /[Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# Autogenerated Jetbrains Rider plugin
[Aa]ssets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.aab
*.unitypackage
*.app

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties

# Packed Addressables
/[Aa]ssets/[Aa]ddressable[Aa]ssets[Dd]ata/*/*.bin*

# Temporary auto-generated Android Assets
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa.meta
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa/*
```

Надеюсь мой ответ будет полезен новичкам.